# quoted string not properly terminated error while sqldeveloper connection

Tags: oracle, docker, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a problem while connect oracle with sqlDeveloper 
In Google search, this Error occur in sql instruction 
but I got this error while connection 
I don't know what is the problem 
my characterset is AL32UTF8, and db is 18c XE 
My OS is macOS and db is running on docker. sqlplus work well 
Sorry. I don't speak english well. Thankyou.
[image]

Comment: does your password by chance happen to have a semi-colon ( ; ) in it, or does the database have any logon triggers?

Comment: @pmdba not there is no semi-colon. because in sqlplus it login well. As far as I know, there is no login trigger. I intall oracle now and do nothing. I installed Oracle today and just created an account

Comment: Is SQL Developer configured to run a login script? The error actually implies that you are getting connected, and then some SQL statement being submitted is incorrect.

Comment: @pmdba I am not sure if the SQL statement is executed internally when I log in. When creating an account, I entered a command `alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;` will this be the problem? Changing it to false now did not solve the problem.

Comment: Did you use a pre-existing Docker image (maybe [this one](https://github.com/fuzziebrain/docker-oracle-xe) )?

Comment: Also, why did you set `_ORACLE_SCRIPT`? That is an underscore parameter, i.e. not for general use. The advice from Oracle Support couldn't be clearer: *"Per Development, setting _ORACLE_SCRIPT to TRUE is something to be used only by Oracle internally.  There may be a case where a note says to use it explicitly, but you should not use it outside the context of that note.  In general is not to be set explicitly by users."*